# How can read chines character from excel (ADODB Connection)

Tags: excel, vbscript, adodb, vba

I have a Excel file with English and Chines character when I try to read the file it gives me weird characters *(?? for Chinese character*)How can I make it give me the correct Chinese characters?

I am using ADODB connection for reading data from excel.

Thanks
Ravi K

Comment: Please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using something like below, there should not be a problem to get the data in Chinese or other Unicode characters. There could be problem if you do a  WScript.Echo(unicodeString) to the console, or if you try to pass that data into some other databases or applications which do not support Unicode.

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
cn.Properties("Extended Properties").Value = "Excel 8.0;"
cn.Open "Excel.xls"
Set rs = cn.Execute("select * from [Sheet1]")
```

please do post your code and highlight the section which produce unexpected output.